# Can I install Microsoft Exchange Server 2010 on a 32bit Virtual Machine?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010

My laptop cannot host 64bit virtual machines. Can I install and use Exchange 2010 on a 32bit machine so I can learn there?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. [Exchange 2010 is 64-bit only](http://www.microsoft.com/exchange/2010/en/us/system-requirements.aspx).

> - An x64 architecture-based computer with Intel processor that
>     supports Intel Extended Memory 64
>     Technology (Intel EM64T) or AMD
>     processor that supports the AMD64
>     platform; Intel Itanium family IA64
>     processors are not supported.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Can I install Exchange 2007 on a 32Bit virtual machine?

Comment: Yes, Exchange 2007 comes with a 32 bit version, **but this is for lab environments ONLY** and is completely unsupported in production.

Comment: Same restriction applies to a VM or real hardware.

Comment: Thanks Ben. Can you tell me where I can get this lab environment only version? Is it pay for? Also, what does Microsoft do that doesn't allow you to use this version in production? In other words how does it 'detect' it's being used in production?  (I'm genuinely curious)

Comment: All these details are on the Microsoft website. You can download it at http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=444c259e-605f-4a82-96d5-a2f448c9d4ff and then this will work for 120 days only. You can use it in production if you're mad but if you ever need to call Microsoft for support, they won't touch it with a bargepole.

Answer (score 4):

In a word, no.

They used to ship a 32-bit evaluation version of Exchange with 2007 but they stopped this for 2010.

http://msexchangeteam.com/archive/2009/05/19/451366.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Can I install Exchange 2007 on a 32Bit virtual machine?

Answer (score 0):

Nope.  Plus Win2k8 R2 is x64 only as well.  MS are ditching x86.